# Close button for pyautogui / keyboard module python

Tags: python, keyboard

I have a program that spams messages, but I need to make such a hot key that will stop the loop, how can I do this?

I trying do this with failsafe, while True wait key, add_hotkey, but it doesn't work

(Sorry for comments in Russian.)

```py
import codecs
import sys
import time
from pathlib import Path
import colorama
import keyboard
from Tools.i18n.makelocalealias import pprint
from art import text2art
import yaml
import pyautogui as pag
pag.FAILSAFE = True
colorama.init()

# Клавиша для активации
hotkey = "9"
# Клавиша для открытия чата
open_hotkey = "shift+t"
# Включить кнопку открытия чата
enable_open_chat_hotkey = True
# Клавиша для отправки сообщения
send_msg_hotkey = "enter"
# Интервал между символами
character_interval = 0
# Интервал между сообщениями
interval = 0.15

close_hotkey = "H+J"


can_run = True

def initConfig():
    global hotkey, open_hotkey, enable_open_chat_hotkey, send_msg_hotkey, character_interval, interval, close_hotkey
    if Path("config.yml").is_file():
        with codecs.open('config.yml', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            loadedConfig = yaml.safe_load(f)
            hotkey = loadedConfig['hotkey']
            open_hotkey = loadedConfig['open_hotkey']
            enable_open_chat_hotkey = loadedConfig['enable_open_chat_hotkey']
            send_msg_hotkey = loadedConfig['send_msg_hotkey']
            character_interval = loadedConfig['character_interval']
            interval = loadedConfig['interval']
            close_hotkey = loadedConfig['close_hotkey']

            print(
                f"Клавиша активации: {hotkey}\n"
                f"Клавиша открытия чата (если включено): {open_hotkey}\n"
                f"Включить ли клавишу для открытия чата в играх?: " + ("Нет", "Да")[enable_open_chat_hotkey] + "\n"
                f"Интервал между символами: {character_interval}\n"
                f"Интервал между сообшениями (рекомендуем оставить 0.2, меньше Дота не тянет): {interval}\n"
                f"Клавиша деактивации: {close_hotkey}\n"
            )

def main():
    print(text2art("1000-7      SCRIPT", "standart"))

    print(
        "Привет, твои текущие настройки программы: \n")
    initConfig()

    keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, lambda: print_1000_7())


    keyboard.wait()

def invert_run():
    global can_run
    can_run = not can_run
    print(can_run)

def print_1000_7():
    print("What is 1000-7?")
    if enable_open_chat_hotkey:
        keyboard.press_and_release(open_hotkey)
        keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a')
        keyboard.press_and_release('backspace')
        time.sleep(interval)

    keyboard.write("What is 1000-7?", character_interval)
    keyboard.press_and_release(send_msg_hotkey)

    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a')
    keyboard.press_and_release('backspace')
    keyboard.press_and_release('F9')
    keyboard.write("What is 1000-7?")
    keyboard.press_and_release(send_msg_hotkey)
    if enable_open_chat_hotkey:
        keyboard.press_and_release(open_hotkey)

    for i in range(5):
        if not can_run:
            return
        print(5 - i)
        if enable_open_chat_hotkey:
            keyboard.press_and_release(open_hotkey)
            keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a')
            keyboard.press_and_release('backspace')
            time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.write(str(5-i), character_interval)
        keyboard.press_and_release(send_msg_hotkey)
        time.sleep(1)

    x = 1000
    while x > 0:
        if not can_run:
            return
        var = x - 7
        if enable_open_chat_hotkey:
            keyboard.press_and_release(open_hotkey)
            keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a')
            keyboard.press_and_release('backspace')
            time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.write(f"{x} - 7 = {var}", character_interval)
        # print(f"{x} - 7 = {var}")
        x = var
        time.sleep(interval)
        keyboard.press_and_release(send_msg_hotkey)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    while True:
        keyboard.wait(close_hotkey)
        invert_run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to python so I'm sure this is not the best answer, also as much as i could understand you want to create a ON\OFF hotkey and i wanted to do same in some program before, so i made sure that my whole program runs only if variable a==True
and i made a hotkey that changes the 'a', so can u do same ? i mean make whole code work only if 'a' variable is set to True

[ofcourse if there is a 'while True' loop inside one of those spam then im not sure that this will work...]

```html
a=True
def b():
    global a
    while a :
        sleep(0.10)
        keyboard.press_and_release('F2')
        for i in range(45):
            sleep(0.1)
            if keyboard.is_pressed('e') :#this is my fail-safe cuz in my program
                                         #i didnt want to wait for the full 4.5 sec in case i wanted to stop
                a=False
        keyboard.press_and_release('f')
        sleep(0.1)
        
b()
while not a:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('e') :
            a=True
            sleep(0.5)
            b()
```

or another version of it

```html
a=True

def Endb():
    global a
    if a==False:
        a=True
    else:
        a=False
        
keyboard.add_hotkey('e',lambda: Endb())

def b():
    global a
    while a :
        sleep(0.10)
        keyboard.press_and_release('F2')
        for i in range(45):
            sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.press_and_release('f')
        sleep(0.1)


b()
while True :
    if keyboard.is_pressed('e'):
        Endb()
        b()
```

this one starts\stops when ever i press 'e' as a toggle for On\Off too, and it saves me the trouble of putting the `if keyboard.is_pressed('e'): a=False` in every step in case i have long code like you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem, i just use `keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey, lambda: on_off(), suppress=True)`
and

```
def on_off():
  global enabled
  enabled = not enabled
```